# CouchDB search by keyword and filter by date at a same time

Tags: couchdb

I have documents with date and name fields

```js
{
  date: '2015-07-16T09:18:36.660Z',
  name: 'australia'
},
{
  date: '2015-08-12T19:11:11.320Z',
  name: 'austria'
},
{
  date: '2016-01-14T12:59:26.120Z',
  name: 'italy'
},
{
  date: '2019-04-28T17:42:10.520Z',
  name: 'spain'
}
```

My map functions looks like this

```js
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.date, doc);
}
```

I can specify date range with ?startkey="2015-01-01T00:00:00Z"&endkey="2017-09-01T00:00:00Z" and that works ok but I would also like to search by keyword within specified date range, let's say additionally to the above range I want all items with name starting with "au"

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is possible out of the box in CouchDB current 1.6.

There is a patch made by Jamie Talbot described in a [blog post](http://jamietalbot.com/2010/03/24/using-multiple-start-and-end-keys-for-couchdb-views/) and some more discussion in [CouchDB's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-523), with the final solution only for 2.0, that achieves what you're asking.

Additionally, there is a new [query language](https://github.com/cloudant/mango) for CouchDB created as an official [Cloudant Query](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html) language which will also be used in CouchDB 2.0.

That said, if using Cloudant or CouchDB 2.0, I'd recommend using the much nicer query language.

First you should create the indices, `POST`ing the index description to the `_index` endpoint:

```js
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      "date",
      "name"
    ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

Then you may use the new query API, `POST`ing JSON to the `_find` endpoint. An example with the criteria you asked:

```js
{
  "selector": {
    "date": {
      "$gt": "2015-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "$lt": "2017-09-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "name": {
      "$gt": "au",
      "$lt": "au\ufff0"
    }
  }
}
```

It is implicitly using an `$and` around the `date` and `name` selectors. You can find further documentation in the links above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your view function to something like,

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.date, doc.name], null);
}
```

Then you can do something like,

```
startkey=["2015-01-01T00:00:00Z,"au"]&endkey=["2017-09-01T00:00:00Z","au\ufff0"]
```

Of course you need to json-encode those key values.

Comment: That's not going to work, because CouchDB matches keys from left to right, so this will skip the second key "au". Any country will match if they are in the date range.